# JDBC Insert Value to database from JTextField

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert the values that I typed in the text field and it would insert into the database (Microsoft SQL) once the actionListener of button is fired.

But whenever I try to insert, it would not insert the values but there isn't any compilation error either. I know this question had been asked quite a lot of times but so far i could not find any solution to my problem.

**EDITED**

> EDIT: i changed from using createStatement to PreparedStatement but im not sure if this is the proper way of writing a preparedStatement
>
> This method is fired when a JButton is pressed.

```
public void createAccount()
{
String idValue = idField.getText();
String pwValue = pwField.getText();
int idValueInt = Integer.parseInt(idValue);
String insertVal = "INSERT INTO Students" +"(StudentID,StudentPW) VALUES"+"
(?,?)";
PreparedStatement prep = null;
try{
    prep = conn.prepareStatement(insertVal);
    prep.setInt(1, idValueInt);
    prep.setString(2, pwValue);
    prep.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Record Added");
    
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

> Connection to the database which is called in the main

```
public void StartConnection(){
try {
        static final String DB_URL = 
        "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Java;
        integratedSecurity=true;";
        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");

        
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }// do nothing
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }//end try               
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: where you call `createAccount`?

Comment: Most probably you are constructing incorrect SQL expression using `+` operator. It is [not recommended](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) to use `+` operator to construct SQL expression strings. Use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to avoid such situations.

Comment: Perhaps print the value of the SQLException, rather than just "ERROR"; it will probably tell you there is a problem with your SQL. I would hazard a guess that, since `idValueInt` is an integer in your Java code, it's probably a number, not a character string in the database. If that is the case, the value probably does not need to be enclosed in quotes. But get the actual error message.

Comment: @Jens inside a JButton actionListener